# C++ GetProcessTimes() does not change value over time

Tags: c++, windows

I'm writing a C++ function for get CPU usage of specific process in Windows.
Many reference (like [this](http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2009/01/03/determine-cpu-usage-of-current-process-c-and-c/)) suggest using function [GetProcessTimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getprocesstimes) for implementation.

However, I tried with a sample program but the value of `KernelTime` and `UserTime` is not changed over times.
Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    int processID = 14532;
    HANDLE processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, processID);
    if (processHandle == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    FILETIME ftProcCreation, ftProcExit, ftProcKernel, ftProcUser;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (!GetProcessTimes(GetCurrentProcess(), &ftProcCreation,
            &ftProcExit, &ftProcKernel, &ftProcUser)) {
            return -1;
        }

        LARGE_INTEGER lKernel, lUser;
        lKernel.LowPart = ftProcKernel.dwLowDateTime;
        lKernel.HighPart = ftProcKernel.dwHighDateTime;
        lUser.LowPart = ftProcUser.dwLowDateTime;
        lUser.HighPart = ftProcUser.dwHighDateTime;

        printf("%lld : %lld\n", lKernel.QuadPart, lUser.QuadPart);

        Sleep(250);
    }

}
```

The process that I inspect is a running Virtualbox process that always take about 20% of CPU.
[image]

However, when I run the sample code, the result is as below:

```
0 : 0
0 : 0
0 : 0
0 : 0
0 : 0
0 : 0
0 : 0
0 : 0
0 : 0
0 : 0
```

Sometimes, it might give following result:

```
312500 : 0
312500 : 0
312500 : 0
312500 : 0
312500 : 0
312500 : 0
312500 : 0
312500 : 0
312500 : 0
312500 : 0
```

Again, it might give following result:

```
156250 : 0
156250 : 0
156250 : 0
156250 : 0
156250 : 0
156250 : 0
156250 : 0
156250 : 0
156250 : 0
156250 : 0
```

Or might be:

```
0 : 156250
0 : 156250
0 : 156250
0 : 156250
0 : 156250
0 : 156250
0 : 156250
0 : 156250
0 : 156250
0 : 156250
```

And so on, but the value of "0:0" is more frequency.

Is there any wrong with my code, so that it cannot get Kernel/Idle time of the process? And why the value does not change over time?

=======

Comment: I have notified something similar. Kernel and user time seems to be only incremented by multiple 156250, regardless how much time thread has been used. You can see the same thing in ProcessExplorer : with threads using very little CPU (eg: 0.1%),"Cycles" is continuously increasing, but kernel and user time are only incremented sporadically, by multiple of 15 ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're querying the time of the *current* process (`GetCurrentProcess()`), not the target process (`processHandle`). Since `GetProcessTimes()` returns the CPU time consumed by the process, but your process isn't consuming much time as it is mostly sleeping, the result changes very slowly.

So, pass `processHandle` instead of `GetCurrentProcess()` to `GetProcessTimes()`.